# DevExtreme Select Box doesn't keep open

Tags: devextreme

I'm using DevExtreme with AngularJS and when I click on a Select Box, it doesn't keep open, I need to click on it 3 or 4 times in order it allows me to select an option.

Do you have any idea why that happens? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going wrong without your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I realized the issue was for Globalize, after I removed it from the project all the components that needed several clicks to open were fixed.